# Bayesian Network calculations given dependence of variables

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

I've been given this bayesian network [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXHBq.png) where $P(A) = P(A = t) = 0.2, P(B) = 0.5, P(C) = 0.8.$

$$\require{enclose}\begin{array}{c}\enclose{circle}{~~A~~}&&&&\enclose{circle}{~~B~~}&&&&\enclose{circle}{~~C~~}\\&\searrow&&\swarrow&&\searrow&&\swarrow\\&&\enclose{circle}{~~D~~}&&&&\enclose{circle}{~~E~~}\end{array}\\\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} A& B & P(D=T\mid A, B)\\\hline F&F&0.9\\\hline F&T&0.6\\\hline T&F & 0.5\\\hline T&T&0.1\end{array}}\hspace{10ex}\boxed{\begin{array}{c|c} B& C & P(E=T\mid B, C)\\\hline F&F&0.2\\\hline F&T&0.4\\\hline T&F & 0.8\\\hline T&T&0.3\end{array}}$$

I wanted to calculate what the probability of A being false was given that all other variables are known to be true. I have come up with 2 different ways and I'm not sure which one is correct, if any of them are in the first place that is.

1. $\small{P(A=f \mid B=C=D=E=t) }~{= (P(A = f) * P(B=C=D=E=t | A = f)) / P(B=C=D=E=t)\\ = 0.8 * 0.5 * 0.6 * 0.3 * 0.8 / ((0.6 * 0.3) + (0.1 * 0.3))}$

   With this one I'm not sure if I calculated P(B=C=D=E=t) correctly.
2. $\small {P(A=f | B=C=D=E=t)} ~{= (P(D|A=f,B=t) * P(E|B=t, C=,t)) / P(B=C=D=E=t)\\ = 0.6 * 0.3 / ((0.6 * 0.3) + (0.1 * 0.3))}$

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: The typesetting is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing this correctly?

No, but you seem to have a *vague* idea of what to do.

---

To save space, I shall use $A^+$ for $A=t$ and $A^-$ for $A=f$, et cetera.

---

Bayes' Rule is not *quite* the right tool to use here, despite this exercise is about Bayesian Network Diagrams.

Rather, you should use the *definition of conditional probability*, and the Law of Total Probability, to state:

$$\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}\begin{align}\P(A^-\mid B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)&=\dfrac{\P(A^-, B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)}{\P(B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\P(A^-, B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)}{\P(A^-, B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)+\P(A^+, B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)}\end{align}$$

What do you do with those?   Okay, now we refer to the diagram.

Well, the Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) says that we have the factorisation: $$\begin{align}\P(A^-,B^+,C^+,D^+,E^+)&=\P(A^-)\P(B^+)\P(C^+)\P(D^+\mid A^-,B^+)\P(E^+\mid B^+,C^+)\\[2ex]\P(A^+,B^+,C^+,D^+,E^+)&=\P(A^+)\P(B^+)\P(C^+)\P(D^+\mid A^+,B^+)\P(E^+\mid B^+,C^+)\end{align}$$

Next, just substitute the numerator and denominator and cancel the common factors $\P(B^+)\P(C^+)\P(E^+\mid B^+,C^+)$, leaving you with:

$$\begin{align}\P(A^-\mid B^+, C^+, D^+, E^+)&=\dfrac{\P(A^-)\P(D^+\mid A^-,B^+)}{\P(A^-)\P(D^+\mid A^-,B^+)+\P(A^+)\P(D^+\mid A^+,B^+)}\end{align}$$

Lastly, just read the values for those factors from the tables and calculate the result.